# Django: How to write clean method to crop photo in blog PostForm?

Tags: python, django, admin

**I want to write a clean method for a blog post form. I want the clean method to open uploaded image and create a newly cropped image and save both.**

My Post model is:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='Post', default='placeholder/placeholder.png')
    small_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='Post/small')
    text = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def publish(self):
            self.published_date = timezone.now()
            self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return revers("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

*Here is my half finished admin.py:*

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Post
        fields = ('author', 'title', 'photo', 'text', 'tags')
```

**If it is the correct way to do things, how would I implement the clean_photo method to save the full size photo and create a newly cropped photo to save as different name (or maybe into different field?)**

Comment: The small_photo field in Post shouldn't be there, I was experimenting and had it there. Maybe it should be there for the future solution...?

Comment: Take a look at [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/packages.html#mezzanine.core.templatetags.mezzanine_tags.thumbnail) for a template based approach or any of [these packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/thumbnails/) for inspriation.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try this!

Comment: If there's something in the question by mistake, it's better to edit the question than leave a comment about the mistake.

Comment: Thanks I will next time